# How to open/tween a gui from the workspace

Tags: lua, roblox

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEHoU.png

What type of code do I put after the "then" line. I need the Gui in StarterGui to tween out when a player does what the script says. If that made sense.

Comment: Heyo, when asking questions, please copy and paste your code in text form into the question. Pictures are nice for looking at your workspace, but really rough for reading code.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the docs and code samples for TweenService (https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/TweenService) or TweenSizeAndPosition (https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/GuiObject/TweenSizeAndPosition) ?

Comment: Yeah I looked into it and I got the gui to tween out using a local script in the gui itself but I need the gui to tween when the player touches a sensor in the workspace. The code I have about shows what happens when a player touches said sensor but I need to know how to make the gui tween from that script. If that makes sense

Comment: And my fault Ill post the code, i'm new to this :)